# How to create endpoint that recognize and parse urlencoded parameter in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, rest, urlencode, x-www-form-urlencoded

There are several similar questions in SO, and I added body-parser, but it doesn't work anyway (see below). My endpoint (and dependencies related to it) looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/auth/refresh/:refreshtoken', async (req, res) => {
// and then verifying refreshToken ...
```

What it does is successful handling the plain request with refreshToken embedded in it as just a part of its url body:

```
@POST("/auth/refresh/{refreshtoken}")
suspend fun refresh(@Path("refreshtoken") refreshtoken: String): AuthResponse<TokenDto>
```

While I need it to handle a request with safe urlencoded field encoded in it (now it returns "404 not found" error):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/auth/refresh")
suspend fun refresh(@Field("refreshtoken") refreshToken: String): AuthResponse<TokenDto>
```

What changes I need to make in that nodeJs andpoint for it?

Comment: Please describe your problem more precisely than just "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made these changes below and now the endpoint works fine.

Before:

```
app.post('/auth/refresh/:refreshtoken', async (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.params.refreshtoken;
    // some code
```

Now (removed field `:refreshtoken` from url and take token from body, not params):

```
app.post('/auth/refresh/', async (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.body.refreshtoken;
    // some code
```